# Intake-STAC: KeyError: 'open_stac_item_collection'

Tags: python, remote-sensing, amazon-web-services, stac

I downloaded the [AWS Earth search notebook](https://github.com/intake/intake-stac/blob/main/examples/aws-earth-search.ipynb) from the intake-stac examples and whithout changing anything. Just run the cells...

But I've got everytime the error: `KeyError: 'open_stac_item_collection'`

Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import intake
import satsearch

bbox = [35.48, -3.24, 35.58, -3.14] # (min lon, min lat, max lon, max lat)
dates = '2020-07-01/2020-08-15'

URL='https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0'
results = satsearch.Search.search(url=URL,
                                  collections=['sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs'], # note collection='sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs' doesn't work
                                  datetime=dates,
                                  bbox=bbox,    
                                  sort=['<datetime'])

items = results.items()

catalog = intake.open_stac_item_collection(items)
```

This is the result/error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/openspacedata_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
     60     try:
---> 61         return gl[attr]
     62     except KeyError:

KeyError: 'open_stac_item_collection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-45f007afa1be> in <module>
----> 1 catalog = intake.open_stac_item_collection(items)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/openspacedata_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
     61         return gl[attr]
     62     except KeyError:
---> 63         raise AttributeError(attr)
     64 
     65 

AttributeError: open_stac_item_collection
```

### Update 1

After the solution of Kadir and replace `intake_stac.catalog.StacItemCollection` with `intake.open_stac_item_collection`, I've got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-0321aa237297> in <module>
----> 1 catalog = intake_stac.catalog.StacItemCollection(items)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/openspacedata_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake_stac/catalog.py in __init__(self, stac_obj, **kwargs)
     61             self._stac_obj = self._stac_cls.from_file(stac_obj)
     62         else:
---> 63             raise ValueError('Expected %s instance, got: %s' % (self._stac_cls, type(stac_obj)))
     64 
     65         metadata = self._get_metadata(**kwargs.pop('metadata', {}))

ValueError: Expected <class 'pystac.catalog.Catalog'> instance, got: <class 'satstac.itemcollection.ItemCollection'>
```

### Update 2

Now this works. But then, I'll get an error on the next line:

```
item = catalog['S2A_36MYB_20200804_0_L2A']
```

### Full error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-60497ae0cb6f> in <module>
----> 1 item = catalog['S2A_36MYB_20200804_0_L2A']

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/openspacedata_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake/catalog/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    415                 out = self[part]
    416             return out()
--> 417         raise KeyError(key)
    418 
    419     def discover(self):

KeyError: 'S2A_36MYB_20200804_0_L2A'
```

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Sure, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

It must be removed from the package. The error says: "there is no such a method in the package".

- Install [`intake-stac`](https://github.com/intake/intake-stac).

  ```
  pip install intake-stac
  ```
- Then, you can use `intake_stac.catalog.StacItemCollection` instead of `intake.open_stac_item_collection` ([Reference](https://intake-stac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/intake.open_stac_item_collection.html#intake-open-stac-item-collection)).

  ```
  import intake_stac

  # ...

  catalog = intake_stac.catalog.StacItemCollection(items)
  ```

Result:

```
<class 'satstac.itemcollection.ItemCollection'>:
  args:
    stac_obj: !!python/object:satstac.itemcollection.ItemCollection
      _collections:
      - &id001 !!python/object:satstac.collection.Collection
        _data:
          description: Sentinel-2a and Sentinel-2b imagery, processed to Level 2A
            (Surface Reflectance) and converted to Cloud-Optimized GeoTIFFs
          extent:
            spatial:
              bbox:
              - - -180
                - -90
...
...
```

**UPDATE:**

The following line gives some results. Please try that:

```
catalog = intake_stac.catalog.Catalog(items)
```

```
null:
  args:
    entries: !!python/object:satstac.itemcollection.ItemCollection
      _collections:
      - &id001 !!python/object:satstac.collection.Collection
        _data:
          description: Sentinel-2a and Sentinel-2b imagery, processed to Level 2A
            (Surface Reflectance) and converted to Cloud-Optimized GeoTIFFs
          extent:
            spatial:
              bbox:
              - - -180
                - -90
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I've got a new error: ValueError: Expected <class 'pystac.catalog.Catalog'> instance, got: <class 'satstac.itemcollection.ItemCollection'> 

Take a look at my question to see the full error message.

Comment: @ScienceNoob I've updated the answer. Please try that.

Comment: This works for that line, but then I'll get an error for the next line. I've updated my question. Is that because of my local configuration or are in the package some errors?